# HDF5 and ROOT Files

Tags: hdf5, root-framework

I routinely use CERN's ROOT framework for data analysis and for storing large amounts of hierarchical data in `.root` files. I am aware that HDF5 files are designed such purposes. What are the differences in how ROOT and HDF5 store and retrieve data? I wish to find out if HDF5 files are suitable for data analysis in particle physics.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I do not think the above statement actually is correct; if you run
`./configure --help`
you will get
`HDFS support; requires libhdfs from HDFS >= x.x`
which rather is file system support and **not** support for HDF5.